# Distinguish between multiple calls of the same view

Tags: android, android-view

I'm currently writing a very simple app which has a TabLayout and 2 fragments: the first one can access the contacts (and works fine), the second one has only one spinner when the activity gets first created.

Depending on the item selected (these are the available orders) a different TableLayout gets inflated and added to a vertical LinearLayout. Some of these  TableLayouts have switches, that if checked can inflate other TableLayouts under them.

Now all of these seems to work fine, except for when I have multiple instances of the same TableLayout. In that case, pressing one of the aforementioned switches only works for one of the TableLayout, not the other ones.

I already know what the problem is (I think), I'm using the `indexOfChild` method to find the view the I need, but since there may be the same view multiple times I'm really lost at the moment.

Could you guys please tell me how to distinguish between the same view called multiple times?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question, but it feels to me you are dynamically adding views to a linear layout on a list type setting. You should probably be using a recycler view to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes I'm adding views dynamically but it's not a list type setting. All these Table Layouts consist of Text Fields and occasionally switches. When I select an item from the spinner a Table Layout gets inflated, then I can input the data that I need and  if I press one of the switches another Table Layout gets inflated just under it in order for me to input more data. I don't know if Recycler View suits my needs, and even if it did, I would like to stick with my solution if possible.